# How to install libqtwebkit5?

Tags: qt5, webkit

How can I install `libqtwebkit5` library?

I need it for a Qt project. I tried with:

```
$ sudo apt-get install libqtwebkit5
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package libqtwebkit5
```

I have this problem on both: 12.04 and 13.10

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your package name has a missing `5`, its name is `libqt5webkit5` not `libqtwebkit5`:

```
sudo apt-get install libqt5webkit5
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  xaw3dg xfig-libs
Use 'apt-get autoremove' to remove them.
The following extra packages will be installed:
  libqt53d5 libqt5core5 libqt5dbus5 libqt5gui5 libqt5location5 libqt5network5
  libqt5opengl5 libqt5printsupport5 libqt5qml5 libqt5quick5 libqt5sensors5
  libqt5sql5 libqt5sql5-sqlite libqt5v8-5 libqt5widgets5 libxcb-icccm4
  libxcb-image0 libxcb-keysyms1 libxcb-randr0 libxcb-render-util0 libxcb-sync0
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  libqt53d5 libqt5core5 libqt5dbus5 libqt5gui5 libqt5location5 libqt5network5
  libqt5opengl5 libqt5printsupport5 libqt5qml5 libqt5quick5 libqt5sensors5
  libqt5sql5 libqt5sql5-sqlite libqt5v8-5 libqt5webkit5 libqt5widgets5
  libxcb-icccm4 libxcb-image0 libxcb-keysyms1 libxcb-randr0
  libxcb-render-util0 libxcb-sync0
0 upgraded, 22 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 18.4 MB of archives.
After this operation, 71.5 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue [Y/n]?
```

Comment: I got this output: `E: Unable to locate package libqt5webkit5`... (12.04) Any solution?

Comment: do copy paste , it will reduce the chances for spelling mistakes.. and make sure you are connected to internet , if you are connecting through others instead of network-manager then please stop it and then try again..

Comment: @Johnツ precise doesn't include the package. Hence you require to add the Ubuntu SDK ppa. http://packages.ubuntu.com/raring/libqt5webkit5 https://launchpad.net/~ubuntu-sdk-team/+archive/ppa

Answer (score 2):

Reason is`libqtwebkit5` isn't in Ubuntu Official Repository. only `libqtwebkit4` is [available](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=saucy&arch=any&searchon=names&keywords=libqtwebkit4). But there is `libqt5webkit5`. But it is [available](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=saucy&section=all&arch=any&keywords=libqt5webkit5&searchon=names) only for 13.04 and 13.10.

If you want to have *qt5webkit version 5* on 12.04 you can get it from **ppa:ubuntu-sdk-team/ppa** [repository](https://launchpad.net/~ubuntu-sdk-team/+archive/ppa/+index?batch=75&memo=75&start=75).

To install from it follow this:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntu-sdk-team/ppa

sudo apt-get update

sudo apt-get install qtwebkit-opensource-src
```

Comment: `E: Unable to locate package qtwebkit-opensource-src` on 12.04

Comment: The previous repository having bugs. So remove it by `sudo add-apt-repository --remove ppa:canonical-qt5-edgers/qt5-beta-proper` and follow the Edited answer.

Comment: Thank you! Hovewer, instead last command for ubuntu 12.04 you have to enter: "sudo apt-get install libqt5widgets5"